# subprocess.call fails calling command with file input

Tags: python, subprocess

The command I want to call looks something like this:

> mycmd arg1 arg2 arg3 < infile.ext >> outfile.ext

where `infile.ext` is a file `mycmd` reads in to execute its process whereas `outfile.ext` is something like a log file.

My `Python` code is:

```
from subprocess import call

impArgs = "%s %s %s < %s >> %s" % (arg1, arg2, arg3, impFilePath, rptFilePath)
impResult = call(["mycmd ", impArgs])
```

I get an `impResult` of 3, no error but the command does not get called. How do I fix this?

Comment: I would appreciate it if negative feedback providers could provide constructive suggestion what to improve in the question rather than simply demanding closure

Answer (score 1):

You are using redirecting features of your shell. `Popen` by default simply launches the process. It does not use shell since in basic case shell is not needed at all.

Either use `shell=True` and pass whole command as string.

from subprocess import call

```
impArgs = "mycmd %s %s %s < %s >> %s" % (arg1, arg2, arg3, impFilePath, rptFilePath)
impResult = call(impArgs, shell=True)
```

Or use piping functionality as [shown in docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
with open(impFilePath) as src, open(rptFilePath) as dst:
    call(['mycmd', arg1, arg2. arg3], stdin=src, stdout=dst)
```

Comment: figured that in the meantime.  see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
impArgs = "%s %s %s < %s >> %s" % (arg1, arg2, arg3, impFilePath, rptFilePath)
impResult = call(["mycmd ", impArgs])
```

I used

```
impCmd = "mycmd  %s %s %s < %s >> %s" % (arg1, arg2, arg3, impFilePath, rptFilePath)
impResult = call(impCmd, shell = True)
```

`shell = True` is what fixed the problem, the result code was 0 and the command was executed.